# using grep --perl-regexp

Tags: bash, grep, regular-expression

this is a sample output of `ls`

```
$ ls -lAF
-rw-------  1 martin martin  168 Jan 25 23:26 aaa
-rw-------  1 martin martin  168 Jan 25 23:26 bbb
-rw-------  1 martin martin  168 Jan 25 23:26 ccc
```

I would like to colorize the `user` and `group` entries. However, my syntax only colorizes `user`,but not the `group`:

```
ls -lAF | grep --color -P '^\S+\s+\S+\s+\K\S+'
```

I don't understand what the `\K` exactly means. How could I match both `martin martin` in my sample output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\K` marks the start of the region to color.

See `man pcrepattern` for details.

> The escape sequence `\K` causes any previously matched characters not to be included in the final matched sequence.

That means you need:

```
ls -lAF | grep --color -P '^\S+\s+\S+\s+\K\S+\s+\S+'
```